# C#: Object is both null and not null

Tags: c#

I'm getting some extremely weird behavior.  An object appears to be null and not null at the same time, and a statement is getting skipped.  I'm probably being an idiot, but if it's my fault I don't see it.  I'm building using Visual Studio 2008 on a Windows 7 SP1 OS.

```
    public void ReadTrendData(OpcDriver opcDriver)
    {
        if (opcDriver != null)
        {
            int a = 1;
        }

        if (opcDriver == null)
        {
            Exception ex = new Exception("Null OPC driver received by ReadTrendData()");
            throw ex;
        }
```

The opcDriver object is successfully created and passed in to this method.  When I step through, the "int a = 1" statement is executed.   Then, in the next if block, execution gets to the "throw ex" statement without executing the line above that creates the ex object.  So, ex is null and throwing null gives me an access violation exception.

Do you have any idea what could be happening here?

A couple of members of the OpcDriver class are instances of classes from a 15-year-old ungauranteed, unsupported sample library that uses COM to interface with an OPC (OLE for Process Control) program.  The only thing I can think of is that somewhere in the bowels of that library something grotesque is happening, but I can't think how this can be possible.

Thank you.

Comment: where is `OpcDriver` - is it overloading any operators?

Comment: I presume you tried the clean, restart VS, clean build routine? Also, I'd set a breakpoint and see what the watch window thinks `opcDriver` is.

Comment: do you have the correct .pdb and source code?

Comment: Just throwing it out. If you use else if then you can't have both of the path returning?

Comment: Perhaps this would be worth trying:
if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(opcDriver, null)) {...}

Comment: Try using Object.ReferenceEquals(null, opcDriver) instead of == and see what you get.

Comment: Why did this get a down vote? It seems like a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: If the class overrides the `==` and `!=` operators weirdly you could see this behavior.

Comment: I'm going to have to guess that somewhere some override of == and != is screwed up.  I tried ReferenceEquals, and got the expected behavior.  Thanks to all who took the time to comment.

Comment: @JAlecksen The question is unanswerable.  It doesn't contain enough information to reproduce the problem.  Why would the question get an upvote, given that you couldn't possibly answer it with the information provided?

Comment: @Servy Understood. I wouldn't think it deserves an up vote, but more specifically does not deserve a down vote. I thought the purpose of asking questions here was to get pointed in the right direction. In this case, the comments most certainly pointed him in the right direction for an otherwise difficult diagnosis.

Comment: @JAlecksen No, the point of questions isn't to "get pointed in the right direction" it's to create a useful repository of knowledge for the larger programming community so that other people with the same problem can find an already-answered question with a quality answer that can also solve their problem.  When the question doesn't contain enough information to be answerable, or to diagnose the problem, it cannot serve that purpose.

Comment: This will happen in VS2008 when you target AnyCPU in your project, the x64 jitter does sometimes generate bad debugging info.  It *looks* like that statement gets executed but that is not actually the case.  Targeting x86 is a simple workaround.  The problems with the x64 jitter got solved in VS2015.

Comment: @Servy

The question was answered by at least two commentators who suggested problematic operator overloading. This provided the opportunity for a workaround which was successful. To sum the discussion up I provide the answer, which is based on the comments of members of the community.

Tthe title is very well chosen, so other programmers who might ever face such a weird behaviour have good chance to solve their issue. The fact the problem is not reproducible makes the problem more frustrating, and the community contribution more important. So it is a good question, and I upvote.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis Several people have provided *guesses* based on incomplete information, in which they have no way of knowing if their answers are correct, because the question lacks sufficient information.  The title is broad enough to cover a wide range of issues, meaning people are going to end up finding the question when they have a range of different problems potentially not covered.

Answer (score 0):

You should try on newer visual studio build. I got almost the same problem on 2008 and 2012 versions. It's a visual studio compile time bug. You should check your build option, if you selected "release" mode you should check back to debug and try again.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, it probably the problem's root is wrong operator overloading (== and/or !=). The test 
`if (Object.ReferenceEquals(opcDriver, null))`
works as expected.